# Set default Timeout on Github action pipeline

Tags: continuous-integration, yaml, github-actions

Normally, my pipelines take 15 minutes to execute.

Recently, for some strange reasons, some pipelines take between 45 minutes and 6 hours to fail.

Is it possible to set a default timeout limit on GitHub Action's pipeline (for example, auto cancel after 30 minutes)?

Answer (score 252, accepted):

You can change default time limit in two ways

- [`job.<id>.timeout-minutes`](https://help.github.com/en/actions/automating-your-workflow-with-github-actions/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idtimeout-minutes) sets a timeout for a whole job
- [`job.<id>.steps.timeout-minutes`](https://help.github.com/en/actions/automating-your-workflow-with-github-actions/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idstepstimeout-minutes) sets a timeout for a single step

Your scenario:

```
my-job:
 runs-on:         ubuntu-latest
 timeout-minutes: 30
```

Comment: If I have many repos and each repo has many actions, it will be very difficult to apply this setting manually on every action. Is there an org level setting, so that the Org Admin can set it and it will get applied for each action in each repo belonging to that org? That way, the Org Admin can control it for all the repos from a central location.

Comment: Is there a way to limit whole action?

Comment: Even I have the same problem as @Ven
I have many repos and want to change this setting at org level, rather than depending upon my devs to do that for their repos. As of now this is clogging my runners.

Comment: @DanielKaplan that link you posted shows that you _cannot_ default per workflow

Comment: @hraban hm. My original comment was, `You can default per workflow: github.community/t/cannot-set-default-timeout-minutes/118164` This was a few years ago so I'm not sure why I said or linked to this at the time. Perhaps it was an unfortunate typo and I meant to say "can**n't**" instead of "can." I'll delete my original comment since it's a red herring.