# Github Actions Workflow for Quarkus Tests

Tags: java, github-actions, quarkus

I am trying to write a github actions workflow to run tests for a quarkus application. However, when running quarkus tests, it runs all the tests, and then displays a command prompt and asks for more commands. This causes the job to hang on github and just keep running indefinitely. I can't figure out how to get quarkus to run all the tests and then just exit.

Here is my current .yml file:

```
name: Java CI with Quarkus

on:
  push:
    branches: [ main ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ main ]

concurrency:
  group: ${{ github.workflow }}-${{ github.event.pull_request.number || github.ref }}
  cancel-in-progress: true

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Set up JDK 17
        uses: actions/setup-java@v2
        with:
          java-version: '17'
          distribution: 'adopt'
      - name: Cache Maven packages
        uses: actions/cache@v2
        with:
          path: ~/.m2
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-m2-${{ hashFiles('**/pom.xml') }}
          restore-keys: ${{ runner.os }}-m2
      - name: Build with Maven
        run: mvn -B package --file pom.xml
      - name: Test with Quarkus
        run: ./mvnw quarkus:test -Dquarkus.test.disable-continuous-testing=true
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `quarkus:test` command is really intended for local, interactive, continuous testing. The advantage of the command is that it will detect code changes and re-run the affected tests automatically. That's awesome locally, but doesn't make sense in a CI.

To run Quarkus tests in 'normal' mode, it's sufficient to just run the normal maven commands, such as `mvn install` or `mvn verify`. In your case, the `mvn package` should be running the tests already, but you could confirm by deliberately committing a failing test and confirming the build fails.

I'm fairly sure that `quarkus.test.disable-continuous-testing` option doesn't exist. I think maybe it's got confused with `quarkus.test.continuous-testing=disabled`, which does exist. That option is mostly intended if you're running with `quarkus:dev` (which runs the application and can also continuously run tests) but only want live reload of the application, and definitely don't want tests.

For your scenario, I'd just remove the `./mvnw quarkus:test -Dquarkus.test.disable-continuous-testing=true` line from your workflow file. That should avoid the interactive session and the Quarkus tests will be run in the previous maven step.

Comment: Just for the clarification, the `mvn package` lifecycle phase will not run all kind of tests, just the "unit tests". In most cases it is fair enough but if you need to run integration tests too `mvn verfiy` or `mvn install` are the right choice.

Answer (score 0):

> This causes the job to hang on github and just keep running indefinitely

A bit off-topic but you should add a time limit for your future jobs.

You can do so with `timeout-minutes`.

For more information, see this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59076067/18289571

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).